# Cannot view image upload to azure blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure, upload, azure-storage

I am using Node.js to upload an image to azure storage https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node. The upload is successful, but I cannot see the image when I visit the URL.

The upload code looks like.

```
var file = 'tmp/myimage.png';
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(config.azure.connection_string);

blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(config.azure.container, 'taskblob', file, function(err, result, response) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(response);
    callback();
});
```

In azure portal I can see something has been uploaded to my container, visiting the provided URL just loads a blank page.

```
https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/taskblob
```

I am also getting a success response back from Azure when logging 'response'

Comment: Can you please check the source and see if you see any XML there? Other things to see if the container ACL is set as `Private`.

Comment: Hey the publicAccessLevel is set to Blob, if thats what you mean? Although looking into it, I can see that the size is 0B, which would indicate some kind of error in the upload, any ideas?

Comment: It would be also nice to assign a Content Type  to the image so it can be accessed from http

Comment: You might want to check your permissions of your container https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/

Comment: @wazzaday， This is strange. Could you please share this blockblob properties by click the 'edit ' on Azure portal? Also, you could upload the text file, and access it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@wazzaday, Generally, we can upload the files into Azure Blob Stroage using the code as you provided.

```
    var azure = require('azure-storage');
    var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService("**","**");
    var file = 'tmp/1.txt';

    blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('mycontainer', function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
        // Container exists and allows
        // anonymous read access to blob
        // content and metadata within this container
            console.log('ok')
        }
    });
    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'myblob1', file, function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('file uploaded'+response)
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

From above code, we need make sure the file path is right.
Because your file size is 0 on Azure Portal, I suggest you can try ReadStream to upload your file and check the file size again. Please refer to this code :

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var fs = require('fs');
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService("**","**");
var file = 'tmp/1.txt';
var stream = fs.createReadStream(file)
var dataLength = 0;
// using a readStream that we created already
stream
  .on('data', function (chunk) {
    dataLength += chunk.length;
})
  .on('end', function () {  // done
    console.log('The length was:', dataLength);
});
blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('mycontainer', function (error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
    // Container exists and allows
    // anonymous read access to blob
    // content and metadata within this container
        console.log('ok')
    }
});



blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream('mycontainer', 'filename', stream,dataLength, function (error) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('ok Blob uploaded')
    }
```

});

Please try above code, any update, please let me know.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, it turns out I was trying to read the image just before it was actually added to the tmp directory. I had to wrap the code in a setTimeout of 0 to wait for the next tick and it worked. The Azure upload code was as you say correct.