# Azure blob image not displaying properly

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I receive the image data as base 64 encoded string and I need to display the contents of the image without downloading it to the server.

My image is not displaying properly when the URL is accessed in a browser

## code

```
public async static Task<dynamic> UploadImageToStorage(string imageData)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(BlobStorageConnectionString);
            try
            {
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(BlobStorageContainer);
                if (await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
                {

                    await container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

                }
                string blobID= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobID);
                blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(imageData);

                return blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                //return blobID;
            }
```

it shows like this

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why are you uploading image data as text?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Please edit your question and include how the imageData looks like.

Comment: @GauravMantri it is base64 value as stated in the question

Comment: The reason I asked to see the actual value is because you’ll need to convert that base64 encoded string to byte array. The value will determine if parsing is required before conversion or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

I converted the incoming string (base 64 image data) to a byte array and stored in memory stream and uploaded to blob.

```
try
{
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(BlobStorageContainer);
    if (await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
    {
        await container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
    }
    string blobID= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobID);
    blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memStream);

    return blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FileMode.Create specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

If your blob size is 0 B. So, you would always couldn't find the file and open it. FileMode specifies how the operating system should open a file.Could delete it and use OpenRead to open an existing file for reading. You could refer to the code as below:

```html
using (var f = System.IO.File.OpenRead(model.FileToUpload.FileName))
            {
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(f);
            }
```

For additional information you may refer to the suggestions mentioned in this   [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526951/cannot-view-image-upload-to-azure-blob-storage) thread and 
[Cannot view image upload to azure blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526951/cannot-view-image-upload-to-azure-blob-storage)

Kindly let me know if you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: I get the base 64 encoded image as the input to the function. Edited the question